# How do find ip address of client using perl

Tags: perl

How do find ip address of client using perl cgi

Answer (score 19):

`$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}` contains the visitor's IP address

Comment: Thanks for not assuming CGI.pm all the time!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you mean CGI.pm, you want [`remote_addr`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#remote_addr())