# Finding the visitors network ip address

Tags: html

I'm interested in finding the visitors ip similar to how www.ipchicken.com does it, can someone nice out there tell me how to do this and send me a simple code?

Comment: It's not HTML, it's done server-side. You can do that with any server-side language.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language supported by your server. Step 2: Find the inevitable duplicate question on SO. e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489078/how-do-find-ip-address-of-client-using-perl) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575722/how-to-get-a-viewers-ip-address-with-python) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683246/get-ip-address-of-client-in-jsp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect the visitor's IP address using HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687642/how-to-detect-the-visitors-ip-address-using-html)

Comment: You can't do it through HTML.However you can find the IP address of a visitor through PHP using $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a third party API service like this [IPIFY](https://www.ipify.org/)

Make an AJAX call to this API and you will get the IP in the response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.ipify.org?format=json"
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("IP: " + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12443524)

Comment: Thanks for the info. :)